# Launching python script with cron job

Tags: python, cron, screen-scraping

I was recently trying to use cron job for my python script on my mac but it is not working properly. I have following simple script for scraping gold price which mark price and time into csv.

```
import csv
import requests
import bs4
from datetime import datetime as dt
import os

# task is to scrape gold price and time from https://markets.businessinsider.com/commodities/gold-price and save it in csv
def get_gold_price():
    page = requests.get("https://markets.businessinsider.com/commodities/gold-price")
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page.text, "html.parser")
    price = soup.find("span", {"class":"price-section__current-value"}).text
    print('The current price is {} USD'.format(price))
    return price

def write_to_csv(price):
    DATE_FORMAT = '%d.%m.%Y %H:%M'
    if "gold_price.csv" in os.listdir():
        mode = "a"
    else:
        mode = "w"
    f = open("gold_price.csv", mode)
    f_writer = csv.writer(f)
    f_writer.writerow([price,dt.now().strftime(DATE_FORMAT)])
    f.close()
print(write_to_csv(get_gold_price()))
```

When I run the script in Pycharm, it is working fine. When I put in my crontab in terminal it is not marking the price every minute.

```
* * * * * /Users/petrsevcik/PycharmProjects/New_Scraping_Project/bin/python /Users/petrsevcik/PycharmProjects/scraping_gold_price/Scraping_Gold_Price.py
```

Any advise please? Is the problem in cron or my script?

Comment: you are using a relative path when using open('gold_price.csv'). The csv file probably ends up in the execution base directory of cron job (wherever this is). Try to use an absolute path instead.

Comment: Does the script run outside of pycharm? If so, try running it with env and the -i option. This will run the script without access to your environment variables like a cron job.